# Pandas: Check if Pandas Dataframe column contains a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where there is a column with DataFrame type values. I would want to check if all the values in that column are of type DataFrame.

```
t_df = DataFrame(data= {
    "r": [1,2,3],
    "r": ['a', 'b', 'c']
})
d = {
    "ts": [1e7, 1e8, 1e9],
    "value": [100, 200, 300],
    "value2": [1, 2, 3],
    "tvalue": [t_df, t_df, t_df]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

if I check `type(df['tvalue'])` it shows - `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` and if I do the same check for `value2` column it shows `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` only.

Is there a way to determine if the all the values inside `tvalue` are of type `DataFrame`.

Comment: Would this work for you? `type(df['tvalue'].iloc[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `all` with `isinstance` by all values in column `tvalue`:

```
print (all((isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) for x in df['tvalue'])))
True
```